# Azure Servicebus: Receive all the message from one session id of a queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have 2 question for which I failed to find any solution.

1. Is there any built in way in azure service bus queue, where I can receive messages only from one session (for that sessionId) in my session handler.
2. Also is there any way I can receive messages only from the deadlettered queue for that session alone.

I can do this programmatically in my code, but I don't want to write if else logic in my code.

Comment: Do you mean you have a session ID from somewhere, and now you want to receive messages of that given session ID? So kind of use the queue for key lookups? Is this ID fixed or does it change over time?

Comment: I am generating session Id per instance of my sender. With same sender multiple requests can be sent. Client can choose to have multiple instances of sender for different kind of requests. Now in each sender I just want to receive messages only for that sessionId and all the deadletter messages for that sessionId.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any built in way in azure service bus queue, where I can receive messages only from one session (for that sessionId) in my session handler.

As Sean Feldman mentioned Queue​Client.​Accept​Message​Session​Async(sessionID) allows to achieve that for a normal queue.

If want to use `Queue​Client.​Accept​Message​Session​Async(sessionID)` to receive queue message, we need to create the with `RequiresSession` **true**,

```
var description = new QueueDescription(QueueName) 
{ 
    RequiresSession = true 
}; 

namespaceManager.CreateQueue(description);
```

> Also is there any way I can receive messages only from the deadlettered queue for that session alone.

Base on my test we can't get the dead-letter queue message from the deadletter queue with following code

```
   var dlqName= QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(queueName);
   var dlqClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionstring, dfQueue);
   var gid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   var messageSession = client.AcceptMessageSession(gid);
   var receiveMessage = messageSession.Receive();
```

> Cannot create a MessageSession for a sub-queue. TrackingId:06a39820-7bf6-412d-ab31-80ef5c174a12_G20_B31, SystemTracker:tomsbservice:Queue: queuename |$DeadLetterQueue

My workaround is that we could get the dead-letter queue message and submit to queue or another normal queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that for Service Bus queues. You can archieve something similar with Service Bus topic and filtered subscription.

So, you send your messages to a topic, and then you'd have to create a subscription per session ID similar to this:

```cs
var filter = new SqlFilter(@"sys.SessionId = \"SESSIONID\"");
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("YOUR_TOPIC", "SESSIONID_SUBSCRIPTION", filter);
```

and then just receive messages from this subscription:

```cs
var client = new SubscriptionClient("...", "YOUR_TOPIC", "SESSIONID_SUBSCRIPTION");
var message = client.Receive();
```

Answer (score 0):

Message Sessions feature is specifically designed for that.

[`Queue​Client.​Accept​Message​Session​Async(sessionID)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.acceptmessagesessionasync?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_AcceptMessageSessionAsync_System_String_) allows to achieve that for a normal queue.
As for the DLQ - not sure if that works.

Comment: DLQ says "Cannot create a MessageSession for a sub-queue"